# Confusion about structs

Tags: c++, struct

It's been a while since I have done C++ so bear with me. I have the following struct:

```
struct  sPage { U16 _; };
typedef sPage tPage;
```

But when I try to do:

```
tPage pagenumber = 0;
```

I get the following error: "No suitable constructor exists to convert from int to sPage". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use a brace initializer `tPage pagenumber = {0};`

Comment: Even easier, `tPage pagenumber{};`

Comment: You cannot say that `tPage` IS an integer, rather it CONTAINS an integer.  And that's how you have to use it, as an aggregate and not a scalar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need curly braces to initialize:

```
tPage pagenumber = {0};
```

or make your own constructor:

```
struct  sPage
{
    U16 _;

    sPage(U16 val) : _(val) { }
};
```

Comment: There can be unexpected effects with implicit constructors like that though, they might be worth noting.

Answer (score 3):

You forgot the braces while initializing. Do it like

```
tPage pagenumber = { 0 };
```